# How to find out stolen phone of android by using IMEI number?

Tags: security

I have already tried by finding
[findDeviceWebsite](https://www.google.com/android/find)

Is there any way to find device by IMEI number?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Find your device through the IMEI number is not really a thing an everyday citizen can do.

Googles find my device is about the best you can do. If the internet and location are off then things will not work. There are website that state they can track based on your IMEI number but then why would they also need your phone number. It is also very doubtful a carrier would give the third party website access to their proprietary information and tools.

Your IMEI number should be consider sensitive information not freely given out to unknown sources.

Another thing you can try is view location history through Google Maps Timeline. If the find my device or location history does not work.

Depending on the laws of your country contact the authorities and file a report. They can then subpoena your carrier to get the location or last known location of the device by triangulating based off their towers.

Answer (score 12):

Track phone by IMEI is nothing but a illusion for normal citizens.
Websites are useless, they only creates backup of IMEI numbers and additional is showing you advertisments along with popping malicious app installation.

• The best way is Google's [Find My Device](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.adm)

Remember:

1. It must be installed in the stolen/lost device along with administrator permission to the app.

   2. To enable this heads to *Settings-Security Settings* under security settings you will find 'administrator permissions'.

      3. Device must be connected to the internet along with enabled 
           location access.

You can do following things with this app:

1. Ring your phone at highest ringer volume even when device is on silent phone.

   2. Secure your device with a password.

      3. Erase your device completely.

Remember: In order this app to work device must be connected to internet with location access(to view it on google maps).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately if your phone did not have any other tracking app installed such as avast or Cerberus (you can use text messages to find your phone through those apps) then you need an internet connection to be able to track your device through googles find my device. Also like previous answer said you can't find your phone through IMEI only the carriers can.